Composition of 2 Piecewise Functions

I'm confused on how to use the boundaries to create the composition. If someone can help me with at least one of them I will try and do the other. Thanks!

Notice that $3 \mid f(n)$ for $n \geq 0$. So, $g(f(n)) = g(3n) = 3n - 1$ for all $n \geq 0$. What about $n < 0$? For $n<0$, we have $g(f(n)) = g(3n+1) = 2(3n+1)+1 = 6n + 3$ because $3 \nmid 3n+1$ for $n < 0$. Therefore,
$$(g \circ f)(n) = \begin{cases}3n - 1 & n\geq0\\6n+3 & n < 0\end{cases}$$
You want to use the restrictions on $f$ to determine what happens when $g$ is applied to $f$.

Just write out the composition and you may see what to do.
So $(g\circ f)(n)=g(f(n))$ is either $g(3n)$ or $g(3n+1)$, so you will need to consider whether $3|(3n)$ (or whether $3|(3n+1)$).
Likewise $(f\circ g)(n) = f(g(n))$ is either $f(n-1)$ or $f(2n+1)$, so you will need to consider whether $n-1\geq 0$ (or whether $2n+1 \geq 0$).
